# Add stacked columns to a cluster chart using dojo

Tags: dojo

I am trying to build a chart using dojo charts.

What we have are four training sessions for each department. We want to display the 'Passed, Not Attempted, Failed' numbers for each test in each department.

Ideally i would like to show my users a cluster column chart with each column corresponding to a training. And then the same column showing stacked numbers for the passed/failed. Four columns together are clubbed for each department.

Is this possible using dojo charts?

Answer (score 0):

You can add plot two times like

```
chart.addPlot("sttt",  {
    type: "StackedLines",
    markers: true,
    tension:"S"
});

chart.addPlot("default", {
    type: ClusturedColumns,
    markers: true,
    gap: 5,
    htmlLabels: false
});
```

[Example in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vusan/Kt9pE/).

Comment: Thanks, but in the clustered columns can the columns be stacked?

Comment: Yes, you just have to code `"dojox/charting/plot2d/StackedColumns"` instead of `"dojox/charting/plot2d/ClusteredColumns"`.